# REST web service available out there to use?

Tags: web-services, api, rest

I was just wondering what other cool web service API out there that we can use besides the following:
1. Foursquare
2. Facebook
3. Twitter
4. Google & Bing Map
5. NetFlix
6. LinkedIn

What other ones can you find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ProgrammableWeb has [an entire database of web APIs](http://www.programmableweb.com/apis), over 2,000 of them so far, organized and searchable. Dive in!

Answer (score 1):

oh man. [Yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/) has a TON of web services . Google has an API called [GData](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/) and it's likewise a ton of things.

Answer (score 1):

A very good Restful API for Sun Cloud platform.

http://kenai.com/projects/suncloudapis/pages/Home